Why is Node.js's fs.watchFile() has default interval of 5007ms?
In the link below, I can see its default interval is 5007ms. I guess it is chosen with tradeoff between responsiveness and overhead.
But why... why that 7ms? A prime number? No. What makes this 7ms look like special?
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fswatchfilefilename-options-listener

My guess is that it exists to avoid an activity spike every 5 seconds that could potentially clash with another every single time. It's a crude "solution" to this, but if some other regular task was also scheduled every 5 seconds and it was initially scheduled at the same time (say, at service start up), then both would require CPU time at the same time, making the total system less responsive than necessary. The extra 7 ms make sure that it doesn't consistently coincide with that other potential task.

Nevermind, I checked the code: they simply took what libev uses ... now to ask that same question again.

libev seems to declare it here, but no comment or commit message explains it, AFAICT: http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.c?revision=1.537&view=markup#l4729
